# AVAudioRecorder - Continue recording to file after user stops recording by leaving the application and then re-opens it

Tags: iphone, audio, ipad, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

Can this be done? And if not, how far down towards Core Audio do I need to go (what method of recording should I be using instead)?

I've noticed the behavior of AVAudioRecorder is to overwrite a file if it finds one at the path provided when you request that it record again, so I know that's not going to work. I'm also curious about file format restriction with this idea. Can you effectively resume an AAC or IMA4 encoding (the length of the files I want to record make WAV and probably even Apple Lossless prohibitive)?

Thanks.

Comment: What API do you use for recording?
What is AVAudioRecorder? > Can you effectively resume an AAC or IMA4 encoding (the length of the files > I want to record make WAV and probably even Apple Lossless prohibitive)? I am not sure I understand the question. But ability and easyness to make append recording without later re-writing two parts (old and new ones) depend on file and audio stream formats. For example it
is easy to implement for pure MP3 files or RIFF-WAV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands right now, it appears AVAudioRecorder cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

As Tegeril says, AVAudioRecorder can't do. What you might be able to do though is record as separate files then concatenate using this answer:

[How to append two audio files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191569/how-to-append-two-audio-files?lq=1)