# iphone recording to an existing file

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

I beleive most of this is going for the database tag but my question is specifically on AVAudioRecorder. Lets say i recorded initially to a file using AVAudioRecorder in the .cif format. 
I want to record someother sound which will append to the recorded file. The recorder will usually overwrite if there is an existing file of that name while initiating.

Answer (score 7):

AVAudioRecorder is not able to append to a recording once created. To do that, you would need to use Audio Tools. See Apple's SpeakHere example.

Comment: sorry i think i havent been looking at the questions i have posted lately. Have put all of them. But some of the answers i could not yet find. thats the problem

Comment: This is also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441180/avaudiorecorder-continue-recording-to-file-after-user-stops-recording-by-leavin