# How to append two audio files?

Tags: iphone, audio

I want to append two audio files in iPhone. Please help me to do this.

Comment: where do you want to do it? pc? on the iphone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution; Following is the sample code to do it.

```
AVMutableComposition* composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVURLAsset* audioAsset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath1] options:nil];
AVURLAsset* audioAsset2 = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath2] options:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack1 = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                      preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[audioTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset1.duration)
                         ofTrack:[[audioAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
                          atTime:kCMTimeZero
                           error:&error];
[audioTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset2.duration) 
                         ofTrack:[[audioAsset2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] 
                          atTime:audioAsset1.duration
                           error:&error];
```

Finally, we have to export it as a single file using `AVAssetExportSession`.

**NOTE: It will work only for .m4a files**

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL) combineVoices1
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL ok = NO;


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;
    //Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionAudioTrack setPreferredVolume:0.8];
    NSString *soundOne  =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test1" ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundOne];
    AVAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    NSArray *tracks = [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack1 = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionAudioTrack setPreferredVolume:0.3];
    NSString *soundOne1  =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundOne1];
    AVAsset *avAsset1 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url1 options:nil];
    NSArray *tracks1 = [avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack1 = [[avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionAudioTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack1 atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack2 = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionAudioTrack2 setPreferredVolume:1.0];
    NSString *soundOne2  =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"song" ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundOne2];
    AVAsset *avAsset2 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url2 options:nil];
    NSArray *tracks2 = [avAsset2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack2 = [[avAsset2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionAudioTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset2.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack2 atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];



    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession
                                           exportSessionWithAsset:composition
                                           presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    if (nil == exportSession) return NO;

    NSString *soundOneNew = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"combined10.m4a"];
    //NSLog(@"Output file path - %@",soundOneNew);

    // configure export session  output with all our parameters
    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundOneNew]; // output path
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A; // output file type

    // perform the export
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status) {
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
        } else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status) {
            // a failure may happen because of an event out of your control
            // for example, an interruption like a phone call comming in
            // make sure and handle this case appropriately
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Export Session Status: %d", exportSession.status);
        }
    }];


    return YES;


}
```

Comment: I am also using similar method. But getting a relatively larger file. Do you know any method to decrease the size. Any idea to adjust sample rate of the output?

Comment: Yeah, I found it then. The export present name controls the quality of the output. Anyways thanks dude.