# iOS AVAudioRecorder insert or append to recording

Tags: ios, insert, append, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I'm in the process of creating an iPhone app to record/playback user dictations with the resulting file being uploaded to a server for speech recognition and transcription. I have everything working apart being able append or insert dictation into a recording thats being created. For example when a user creates a dictation they will record some speech, then play back some or all of that speech recording, then switch back into recording. The subsequent speech recording should append itself if the payback reached its end or overwrite the original record at the point the user stopped the playback.

I have been looking for a solution to this for a couple of weeks now and found nothing but vague suggestions, I also got a copy of the Learning Core Audio book but I'm no further forward. If anyone can shed some light on how to proceed I would be most grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154125/how-can-i-append-to-a-recorded-mpeg4-aac-file