# How to merge audio file in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I am working on audio mixing file. In this i want to merge multiple audio files into one file.
i am using appending two audio files but the result output is coming only first audio file.please any one give suggestion for this issues.

Comment: Please check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191569/how-to-append-two-audio-files

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the file header so that an audio player would know that the appended data exists?  look at the specs for the audio file format you are using.

Comment: thank you  for reply can u explain how to edit the file header for audio and if you have any sample code please send me if it is very useful for me.